# Get Value From 'param' Of 'views.py' In Javascript Django

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, django-views, view

In views.py

```
def website(request, pk=None):
if not model_utils.check_admin_permission(request): 
    return loginAndContinuosRequest(request)

if pk:
    obj = get_object_or_404(Website, pk = pk)
    form = WebsiteForm(instance=obj)
    fields = obj.get_manage_payment_accounts()
else:
    obj = None
    form = WebsiteForm()
    fields = []

if request.POST:
    if pk:
        form = WebsiteForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=obj)
    else:
        form = WebsiteForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("views_manage_websites"))

params = {
    'obj':obj ,
    'form':form,
    'fields': fields,
    'test': 'test',
}

return render(request, TEMPLATE_PATH + 'website.html', params)
```

In script in template (.html),

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert({{ obj.id }}); //(1)
        alert({{ obj.pk }}); //(2)
        alert({{ obj.site_name }}); //(3)
        alert ({{ test }}); //(4)
    });

</script>
```

The alert (1) and (2) is shown. But the alert (3) and (4) isn't shown. 
Can you explain for me.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the instance of the model that you are using have a value for that field (site_name)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj.site_name` and `test` are strings. In JavaScript, as in Python, strings need to be surrounded by quotes.

```
    alert("{{ obj.site_name }}");
    alert("{{ test }}");
```

Your browser's developer tools will have shown the original code generating a syntax error.